# YAFFS2(Direct) file system for NAND flash on a stand alone System

Tags: filesystems, embedded, flash-memory

I need to port YAFFS2 flash file system to a stand alone system based on ARM Cortex A9 processor. The environment is single threaded. The flash is 8Gb NAND Flash from Micron. Can any one suggest useful materials or please explain regarding **the steps involved in YAFFS2 Direct porting?** I have already gone through YAFFS Direct User Guide provided in www.yaffs.net. I'm just a beginner in Embedded Programming. Thanks in advance.